# Conditionally Run SSR or CSR using React

Tags: reactjs, next.js, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I currently have a website that uses SSR (using nextJS) to render the landing page in the root directory. However, I want the website to render my create-react-app application when the user is logged in. When the user is logged out, I want the website to show the landing page.

So my question is, is it possible to conditionally render using SSR when logged out, and use CSR when logged in? I'm just looking for general guidance on how to build the architecture that handles such event.

(The reason why I use SSR is for SEO reasons. My app doesn't need SEO so I want to use CSR instead. I also want to avoid using subdomains for now.)

Answer (score 2):

It is possible with two options below:

- (Recommended) Create a proxy server (just another Node server on top of your SSR and CSR servers), and implement the logic to proxy requests to either SSR or CSR in different cases. Or,
- Create a custom Next server and route any logged-in requests to CSR. However, this option will sacrifice some major Next features.